# Wiremock/Mockserver with custom Domain Name?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, wiremock, mockserver

I'm trying to do a test where my client allows the use of wildcard certificates (ie. CN=*.dev.domain). I'm trying to setup a mock server that has this certificate in its keystore, but I need to customize the mock server's domain into something like test.dev.domain so that my client under test can route to it.

Is there a way to do this using Wiremock/Mockserver or any other server mock in Java? http://wiremock.org/docs/multi-domain-mocking/ does something close to what I need but not exactly.